# Call PostgreSQL stored procedure using SimpleJdbcCall and REF_CURSOR

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I want to call a PostgreSQL stored procedure with REF_CURSOR using SimpleJDBCCall. My stored procedure looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.procName()
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
  ref1 refcursor := 'cursor';
BEGIN
   open ref1  for SELECT *   FROM public."tableName";
   RETURN ref1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.procName()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

I tried to call the procedure using the following JAVA code:

```
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);


    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
    jdbcCall.withFunctionName("procName").returningResultSet("cursor",
            BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(CustomEntity.class));

     Map m = jdbcCall.execute();
```

Running the code I received an error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "cursor" does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLQuery(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:339)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.internalGetObject(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:213)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3ResultSet.internalGetObject(AbstractJdbc3ResultSet.java:36)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4ResultSet.internalGetObject(AbstractJdbc4ResultSet.java:312)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getObject(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2711)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:457)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:413)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1068)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1066)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1016)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1066)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:397)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:369)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:173)
```

I tested this code using an Oracele stored procedure, also with REF_CURSOR. I used instead of `withFunctionName()` the `withProcedureName()` method. The stored procedure is correctly called, and the result is returned.

Is there a way to call the PostreSQL stored procedue which is returning a  REF_CURSOR using SimpleJDBCCall?

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("genidproc");
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("keystr", "uno");
Map<String, Object> result = call.execute(params);
for (String s : result.keySet()) {
     pw.println("6.0  " + result.get(s));
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.